# Block/Redirect IP's or hosts without hosts file in c# 2.0

Tags: c#, redirect, dns, ip, block

this question is very hard to find the answer to. I would like to block a list of domains, say, if anything under google.com entered the DNS and was received it would redirect or close the connection stopping say a malicious website from accessing the hosts computer. I have heard iphlpapi.dll is of use with this, but there is very little or no user friendly information about this DLL and its usage. I am not going above .net 2.0 and my language is C#. Thanks :).

I would like to (at least one of these)

Block a set of domains from a main domain
Block a certain IP or range
Redirect a set of domains from a main domain
Redirect a certain IP or range.

Preferably not requiring admin or UAC privileges.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Vista/7 you can use the built-in firewall to block any host using NetFwTypeLib (Located in FirewallAPI.dll)

```
    using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using NetFwTypeLib;
namespace WinFirewall
{
    public class FWCtrl
    {
        const string guidFWPolicy2 = "{E2B3C97F-6AE1-41AC-817A-F6F92166D7DD}";
        const string guidRWRule = "{2C5BC43E-3369-4C33-AB0C-BE9469677AF4}";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FWCtrl ctrl = new FWCtrl();
            ctrl.Setup();
        }
        public void Setup()
        {
            Type typeFWPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(guidFWPolicy2));
            Type typeFWRule = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(guidRWRule));
            INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWPolicy2);
            INetFwRule newRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWRule);
            newRule.Name = "InBound_Rule";
            newRule.Description = "Block inbound traffic from 192.168.0.2 over TCP port 4000";
            newRule.Protocol = (int) NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
            newRule.LocalPorts = "4000";
            newRule.RemoteAddress = "192.168.0.2";
            newRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
            newRule.Enabled = true;
            newRule.Grouping = "@firewallapi.dll,-23255";
            newRule.Profiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;
            newRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;
            fwPolicy2.Rules.Add(newRule);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try `string restricted ="IP.IP.IP";`

It could also be a website address `string restricted = "www.website.com";`